# Error on null properties after upgrading flutter version

Tags: flutter, dart, null, nullable

can anyone solve the error of null operation in my code?
[image]

I'm already changing the operator for many times and im still confusing why this still show the error, this is the highlighted error:

```
 StreamBuilder<CastResponse>(
          stream: castsBloc.subject.stream,
          builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<CastResponse> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              if (snapshot.data?.error != null &&
                  snapshot.data?.error.length > 0) {
                return _buildErrorWidget(snapshot.data.error);
              }
              return _buildCastWidget(snapshot.data);
            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return _buildErrorWidget(snapshot.error);
            } else {
              return _buildLoadingWidget();
            }
          },
        )
      ],
    );
  }
```

and also this one:

```
   Widget _buildCastWidget(CastResponse data) {
        List<Cast> casts = data.casts;
```

if you wondering how the model looks like:

```
class Cast {
  final int id;
  final String character;
  final String name;
  final String img;

  Cast(this.id,
        this.character,
         this.name,
         this.img);

  Cast.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : id = json["cast_id"],
        character = json["character"],
        name = json["name"],
        img = json["profile_path"];
}
```

can you help me to solve it if you know how

Answer (score 1):

Flutter shows an error because `snapshot.data` can be null.
You check with the previous `if` statements that it is not null, so you can safely change `snapshot.data?.error` to `snapshot.data!.error`

The `!` operator simply tells flutter that the nullable variable is not null, so you will stop seeing the error.